# Unable to extract value using xpath query

Tags: html, xpath

Learning to use xpath queries. I am having an issue were I am unable to extract a value that changes whenever the page is refreshed. 
For example, I am trying to extract the value '62804' from the following html code: "canvas.strokeText('Answer: 62804',90,112);" . Any ideas how this can be done. Thanks

```
<html>
<div id="content" class="large-12 columns">
        <div class="example">
  <h3>Challenging DOM</h3>
  <p>The hardest part in automated web testing is finding the best locators (e.g., ones that well named, unique, and unlikely to change). It's more often than not that the application you're testing was not built with this concept in mind. This example demonstrates that with unique IDs, a table with no helpful locators, and a canvas element.</p>
  <hr>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns large-centered">
      <div class="large-2 columns">
        <a id="debcda40-b692-0137-457b-2213fbd48497" href="" class="button">qux</a><br>
        <a id="debce410-b692-0137-457c-2213fbd48497" href="" class="button alert">baz</a><br>
        <a id="debd03d0-b692-0137-457d-2213fbd48497" href="" class="button success">foo</a><br>
      </div>
      <div class="large-10 columns">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Lorem</th>
              <th>Ipsum</th>
              <th>Dolor</th>
              <th>Sit</th>
              <th>Amet</th>
              <th>Diceret</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

            <tr>
              <td>Iuvaret0</td>
              <td>Apeirian0</td>
              <td>Adipisci0</td>
              <td>Definiebas0</td>
              <td>Consequuntur0</td>
              <td>Phaedrum0</td>
              <td>
                <a href="#edit">edit</a>
                <a href="#delete">delete</a>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Iuvaret1</td>
              <td>Apeirian1</td>
              <td>Adipisci1</td>
              <td>Definiebas1</td>
              <td>Consequuntur1</td>
              <td>Phaedrum1</td>
              <td>
                <a href="#edit">edit</a>
                <a href="#delete">delete</a>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Iuvaret2</td>
              <td>Apeirian2</td>
              <td>Adipisci2</td>
              <td>Definiebas2</td>
              <td>Consequuntur2</td>
              <td>Phaedrum2</td>
              <td>
                <a href="#edit">edit</a>
                <a href="#delete">delete</a>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Iuvaret3</td>
              <td>Apeirian3</td>
              <td>Adipisci3</td>
              <td>Definiebas3</td>
              <td>Consequuntur3</td>
              <td>Phaedrum3</td>
              <td>
                <a href="#edit">edit</a>
                <a href="#delete">delete</a>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Iuvaret4</td>
              <td>Apeirian4</td>
              <td>Adipisci4</td>
              <td>Definiebas4</td>
              <td>Consequuntur4</td>
              <td>Phaedrum4</td>
              <td>
                <a href="#edit">edit</a>
                <a href="#delete">delete</a>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Iuvaret5</td>
              <td>Apeirian5</td>
              <td>Adipisci5</td>
              <td>Definiebas5</td>
              <td>Consequuntur5</td>
              <td>Phaedrum5</td>
              <td>
                <a href="#edit">edit</a>
                <a href="#delete">delete</a>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Iuvaret6</td>
              <td>Apeirian6</td>
              <td>Adipisci6</td>
              <td>Definiebas6</td>
              <td>Consequuntur6</td>
              <td>Phaedrum6</td>
              <td>
                <a href="#edit">edit</a>
                <a href="#delete">delete</a>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Iuvaret7</td>
              <td>Apeirian7</td>
              <td>Adipisci7</td>
              <td>Definiebas7</td>
              <td>Consequuntur7</td>
              <td>Phaedrum7</td>
              <td>
                <a href="#edit">edit</a>
                <a href="#delete">delete</a>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Iuvaret8</td>
              <td>Apeirian8</td>
              <td>Adipisci8</td>
              <td>Definiebas8</td>
              <td>Consequuntur8</td>
              <td>Phaedrum8</td>
              <td>
                <a href="#edit">edit</a>
                <a href="#delete">delete</a>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>Iuvaret9</td>
              <td>Apeirian9</td>
              <td>Adipisci9</td>
              <td>Definiebas9</td>
              <td>Consequuntur9</td>
              <td>Phaedrum9</td>
              <td>
                <a href="#edit">edit</a>
                <a href="#delete">delete</a>
              </td>
            </tr>


        </tbody></table>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="large-10 columns">
            <canvas id="canvas" width="599" height="200" style="border:1px dotted;"></canvas>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>

<script>
var canvas_el = document.getElementById('canvas');
var canvas = canvas_el.getContext('2d');
canvas.font = '60px Arial';
canvas.strokeText('Answer: 62804',90,112);
</script>

      </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the XPath query the input document must be a valid XML.
In your case it isn't, because there are some tags that are not properly closed (you can verify it using an XMLLint tool).
E.g.

`<hr>` and `<br>` should be replaced with `<hr/>` and `<br/>`.

Once the XML is corrected, you can use an XPath query.

The fist step is select the script element:

```
//script
```

The output is:

```
Element='<script>
            var canvas_el = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var canvas = canvas_el.getContext('2d');
            canvas.font = '60px Arial';
            canvas.strokeText('Answer: 62804',90,112);
        </script>'
```

Then you have to convert the Element Node in a String and then perform some parsing:

```
substring-before(substring-after(//script/text(), 'canvas.strokeText(''Answer: ') , ''',90,112)')
```

The result is the following:

```
String='62804'
```

**Note:** You can do the same operation in a more elastic way using Javascript, for example.
XPath is very good to query an XML (like the first operation that I mentioned) but quite complicated to do String parsing (like the second operation that I mentioned).

Hope it can help.

Comment: @Prerna pal I should have included in the original comment, that this xpath query is for an java selenium project. I have try using the above xpath in the code but getting an 'NoSuchElementException'.

Comment: Hi @trant7, if you try the same query with the input corrected it should work. I tested it with an online tool.

A few question:
- Do the first xpath query work? `/html/div/script`
- Can you share the Java code?

Comment: Hi @Prerna pal, I tested your original query "substring-before(substring-after(/html/div/script/text(), 'canvas.strokeText(''Answer: ') , ''',90,112)')" in an online xpath tester but it did not work. Update the query to the following "substring-before(substring-after(//script/text(), 'canvas.strokeText(''Answer: ') , ''',90,112)')" and it worked. When I try the query in java, I get the following error "org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector:

Comment: I updated the response. If is fine with it can you please mark as answered.